Covering up/containing musty smell from old painted wood paneling?
I live in a rental and one of the rooms has old wood paneling of some sort, that was painted over many times. It's also musty in that room and it smells like it's coming from the paneling.
Is it possible that some peel and stick wallpaper would help contain that mustiness? Or something else that's temporary and a better option that doesn't cost a ton? I don't even care about filling the lines of the paneling, mainly if it would contain the smell. It's a well-ventilated room in general but gets pretty hot from facing the sun.
I know that mustiness isn't a good thing in general and indicates dry rot/breaking down of material and so on, but don't have the option to move or get the landlord to update it.
Thanks!
